# Why does Excel make un-expanded dates unreadable to other software?

Tags: r, excel, date, google-sheets, column-width

I recently ran into an issue in R where it wasn't reading the date values from my csv file. I had reviewed and revised my code many times before realizing the source of the issue was the file itself. After experimentation, I realized that the date would only read if I expanded the date column in Excel and then resaved the file. This doesn't seem logical to me, the data is stored in the spreadsheet so while I expect Excel to make it unreadable to the human eye until the column is expanded, I did not expect it to be unreadable to another computer program, in this case, R. **I feel that I got lucky discovering this and would like to understand why it works that way?**

It helps to mention that I noticed a very similar issue when pasting un-expanded dates from Excel to Google Sheets; the result is cells filled with "######" instead of the actual date values.

Because Excel is the common party here I'm assuming this is an Excel issue.

**What is happening with Excel to make the un-expanded date values unreadable to other software?** Is this something that Excel is aware of?

**Un-expanded dates**

[image: Un-expanded Dates]

**R-Misread**
[image: r not reading the date values]

**Google Sheets Paste**
[image: Copy and pasting to google sheets gives # sign instead of date values]

After expanding the column in the csv file and saving it, both the R issue and the Google Sheets issue went away.

Comment: What function are you using to read in the data? Are you reading in a CSV, XLS or XLSX file?

Comment: have you tried (in your excel) increasing the column-width of the columns that display `######` ?

Comment: What is the actual contents of that cell in Excel? What do you see if you examine the actual CSV file with a text editor.  I cannot reproduce your problem in Sheets. Could the cell contents be a negative value formatted as date/time?

Comment: @ToddBurus I'm reading it 3 ways. The original file is csv that I'm reading in Excel; Wimpel Yes I'm aware that expanding the column width displays the data, that's not my question, my question is why are the machines/software unable to read the data even if you don't expand it? Ron Rosenfeld I will update later today with a photo of actual contents.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  I think if you use any Dates and make the column width small enough so that it shows as only "#####" then save it; that should allow you to reproduce it.

Comment: That is exactly what I did. Then I saved the worksheet as `.csv`.  And, as I wrote, I was unable to reproduce your problem. The date showed up properly in Sheets.  And also in the Raw CSV file (opened with a text editor).

Comment: How are you reading the data into R?

Comment: GOing to add some of my R script to the original post to help answer some of these questions. I will say I have only come across this issue when I've downloaded a data set from a site/source. I'll see if I can share a tiny version of the data set. I've never share a data file here so I'll have to look into how to do that first.  To directly answer you @ToddBurus I'm using the readcsv funciton:
main_df <- read.csv("mail.csv", na.strings=c(""," ","NA"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE )

Comment: @TSmith Could you just open the CSV in a text editor (i.e. Notepad or equivalent) and share the first couple of lines of it? Maybe also share `str(df)` from R.